# How to batch interpolate many shapefiles to DEM

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, pyqgis, qgis-2

Here´s the problem: I have about 40 shapefiles of contour lines (type line) and I need to interpolate them to create DEM's (tiff, or better some grid format). To do so, some batch scripting would be nice but I just can't figure out a good way.

I could do it with the batch tools of QGIS (GRASS v.bspline would do the job), but I would need to set the parameters for EACH single run. Not very slick at all. So I tried to do it with SAGA CMD in a bash script, but the problem is that the interpolation function needs the input of the area extension and I don't really know how to code that again.

It´s my first real contact with coding for GIS or Python but I've programmed before in Matlab and know some Linux bash stuff so that should not be too much of a problem.

So can anyone help me with a simple way to batch script basically what the Interpolation Plugin of QGIS does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17432/how-to-smooth-interpolate-a-raster-in-python-using-gdal

Comment: @nickves The duplicate that you cite makes no mention of how to batch process which I think is the focus of this Question.  Consequently, I am voting to leave it Open.

Comment: Check this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18354/batch-create-dem-from-contour-maps-open-source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a (very raw!) script for use in GRASS to process a shapefile and create a DEM tile. Four requirements:

1. You must be in a GRASS session to run this
2. You must have a GRASS location setup that matches the CRS of the
   shapefiles
3. You must have the resolution set to a reasonable number in GRASS's
   region settings
4. The contours shapefile needs an elevation column named "level" here

   #!/usr/bin/env python

   ```
   """
   Interpolate a dem from a line shapefile
   The shapefile name is passed on the command line
   It must have a column named "level" with elevation values 
   """

   import os, sys
   import grass.script as grass

   if "GISBASE" not in os.environ:
       print "You must be in GRASS GIS to run this program."
       sys.exit(1)

   if len(sys.argv) < 2:
       print 'No shapefile specified'
       sys.exit(1)

   # Get shapefile name on command line
   shp_path    = sys.argv[1]
   shp         = os.path.basename(shp_path)
   ctour_orig  = os.path.splitext(shp)[0].lower()
   ctour       = ctour_orig.replace(' ','_')
   ctour_rast  = ctour + '_rast'
   dem_tile    = ctour + '_dem'

   print "Processing shapefile: %s" % ctour

   grass.run_command('v.in.ogr', dsn=shp_path, output=ctour, type='line', overwrite=True)
   grass.run_command('g.region', flags='p', vect=ctour, overwrite=True)
   grass.run_command('v.to.rast', input=ctour, output=ctour, type='line', use='attr', attrcol='level', overwrite=True)
   grass.run_command('r.surf.contour', input=ctour, output=dem_tile, overwrite=True)

   print "Completed creating raster tile: %s" % dem_tile
   ```

If you save the script as "shp_to_dem.py" then you could loop thru the the shapefiles in a directory and pass each to this script with something like (on Linux):

```
for s in *.shp; do python shp_to_dem.py $s; done
```

Maybe this will get you started.